# Facet pivots on Solr 3.5

Tags: solr, faceted-search

We need to generate word counts for a group of records and then we need to generate subtotals based on another field's values for each word counted. We know that's possible using pivot faceting on Solr 4. Is that possible with Solr 3.5? If so, how could that be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pivot / nested faceting in SOLR prior to 4.x.

The solution generally involves faceting once, and using each facet value as a tagged **fq**. Then you facet excluding each tagged fq.

This is somewhat a killer query, but it does the job.

You can see a more elaborate example at http://loose-bits.com/2011/09/20/pivot-facets-solr.html that does exactly that, comparing SOLR 4 with 1.4 syntax (SOLR 3.x is really similar to 1.4 in that sense)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, we already looked at that option but seems limited in the sense that the first level of the tree will require a known group of options, while in our case, the first level of the tree would be the counted words.

Comment: Did you try with [TermVectorsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent) and then query based on the info you got there?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to implement this using TermVectorsComponent?